# Spring MVC JSON producer takes too long in some cases

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Background : My application is a web based application using :

- Spring 3.1.0 Release
- Jackson 1.9.2

Details : 
I have a simple class (lets call it MyClass) that stores,something like an int, a String and a byte[].
I do a HTTP call that invokes the method below:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getMyObj", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @ResponseBody
    public MyClass getMyObj(@RequestBody String id {
        try{
                     MyClass myObj=myService.getMyClassObject(id);
             return myObj;
        } catch (Exception e){
            return ErrorResult(APIError.ERROR,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The byte array is filled (by my service layer via my dao layer) with the binary content stored in a database (imagine a small text file content), which works fine.IOW, myObj is constructed well.
The issue is that it takes very long to get the result in a browser.
Example :  500 KB - 16 minutes.

If I stream the file directly (code below), it is really fast (like 1 sec). 
For sure, I would expect that the first approach to be slower...but not at this difference.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getFile(@PathVariable("id") String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.reset();
        myService.get(id, new MyHttpConsumer (response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class MyHttpConsumer implements MyConsumer {
        private HttpServletResponse response;
        public MyHttpConsumer (HttpServletResponse response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

        public void setContentType(String contentType) {
            response.setContentType(contentType);
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return response.getOutputStream();
        }
    }
```

I've tried to somehow improve the serialization using a custom ObjectMapper.

```
   <bean id="myObjectMapper" class="com.*.*.MyObjectMapper"/>      
    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="myObjectMapper" />
                </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>   
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

No luck...
It is worth,perhaps,saying that if I serialize myObj (of type MyClass) ignoring the byte[] 
everything works fine : fast answer.Check the Serializer below.

```
   class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass>
    {
        @Override
        public void serialize(MyClass value, JsonGenerator jgen,
                SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
                JsonProcessingException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            byte[] b= values.getContent();
            jgen.writeBinaryField("content", b);
                //jgen.writeFieldName("id");
            //jgen.writeNumber(value.getId());
            jgen.writeEndObject();

        }
    }
```

and I am registering my serializer

```
module.addSerializer(MyClass.class, new MySerializer());
```

To summarize : what I am looking for is a fast (faster) response to getMyObj call, considering that myObj stores a byte array.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not constrained to Jackson1, I recommend:

1. [Jackson 2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)
2. [Jackson Afterburner Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-afterburner/)

Jackson also has serialization features you can toggle: specifically, [FLUSH_AFTER_WRITE_VALUE](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesSerialization?highlight=%28%5CbFLUSH_AFTER_WRITE_VALUE%5Cb%29) might help.

Comment: How would one go about toggling these features in a Spring XML context file?

Comment: @anton1980: I think it's better done at the dependency management level.  For example, if you were using Maven, you would declare the <version> dependencies.